# Gawk Line removal, Splitter is :

Tags: bash, grep, gawk

Is it possible to move certain columns from one .txt file into another .txt file?

I have a .txt that contains:

```
USERID:ORDER#:IP:PHONE:ADDRESS:POSTCODE
USERID:ORDER#:IP:PHONE:ADDRESS:POSTCODE
```

With gawk I want to extract ADDRESS & POSTCODE columns into another .txt, so for this given file the output should be:

```
ADDRESS1:POSTCODE1
ADDRESS2:POSTCODE2
```

etc.

Comment: I'm lost: do you want the output on separate lines? because it wasn't the case at first.

Comment: The briefest glance at an awk man page or tutorial would show you how to do that. Put **SOME** effort into solving problems yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic AWK transform.  You want to use "-F :" to specify that the input is delimited by ":" and print a new ":" on output:

```
awk -F: '{ print $5 ":" $6 }' <input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
awk -F: '{printf "%s:%s ",$5,$6}' ex.txt
```

input is

```
USERID:ORDER#:IP:PHONE:ADDRESS1:POSTCODE1
USERID:ORDER#:IP:PHONE:ADDRESS2:POSTCODE2
```

output is (on one line if I understand correctly)

```
ADDRESS1:POSTCODE1 ADDRESS2:POSTCODE2
```

only default is that it ends with a trailing space and does not end with a newline.

Which can be fixed with the slightly more complex (but still readable):

```
  awk -F: 'BEGIN {z=0;} {if (z==1) { printf " "; } ; z=1; printf "%s:%s",$5,$6} END{printf"\n"}' ex.txt
```

Comment: Quick question, how do I specify which .txt file for the program to use.. or is ex.txt the input file & not the output?

Comment: `ex.txt` is the input. To redirect to a file just add `> out.txt` in the end.

Comment: error,

gawk: 'BEGIN
gawk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: works fine here on MSYS or DOS CMD.exe. Have you tried both solutions? which one fails for you? I'm using GNU Awk 4.1.3. Can you type `gawk --version` and tell me the result.

Comment: I have 3.1.6 atm :/

Comment: nothing fancy in my awk code. Are you running from a windows terminal? MSYS? Linux ? Can you upgrade? and tell us what the caret points to (`^`) in the above message (the line above we don't have). You can also put the expression between simple quotes in a file and use `-f` option instead of passing the whole command as a parameter.

Comment: im using a .bat filon windows, uhm i can't seem to find a version of 4.1.3

Comment: Atandard advice in Windows is to put the awk script in a file and execute it as `awk -f script` to avoid Windows quoting hell. Better yet - install/use cygwin.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the support, @Jean-FrançoisFabre your script works :) & Ed Morton thank you for cygwin, that was the solution i needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: 'NR==1 {print $5"1:"$6"1"};NR==2 {print $5"2:"$6"2"}' file
ADDRESS1:POSTCODE1
ADDRESS2:POSTCODE2
```